# How to convert Vuejs1 to Vuejs2

Tags: vue.js

Im beginner in VueJS.
This code built with vuejs 1

https://codepen.io/jjelic/pen/yevNLZ

I dont know how to make this code work in vuejs2.

All i can do just change this code

```
data: {
    rows: [
        //initial data
        {qty: 5, description: "Something", price: 55.20, tax: 10},
        {qty: 2, description: "Something else", price: 1255.20, tax: 20},
    ],
    total: 0,
    grandtotal: 0,
    taxtotal: 0,
    delivery: 40
},
```

into this

```
data: {
    rows: [
        //initial data
        {qty: 5, description: "Something", price: 55.20, tax: 10},
        {qty: 2, description: "Something else", price: 1255.20, tax: 20},
    ],
    grandtotal: 0,
    delivery: 40
},
```

I know that Vue.Filter is deprecated in vuejs2, and i dont know how to convert that in vuejs2

Help me. Thanks :)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ad

Comment: <input class="form-control text-right" :value="row.qty * row.price" v-model="row.total" number readonly />

this works great in vuejs 1, but not in vuejs 2. Still confuse :(